# How not to open a new tab on clicking middle mouse button?

Tags: reactjs

I want to open a new page in the same tab on clicking middle mouse button.

Here is what i am trying to do...
I have a card component that contains image and footer. When i click middle mouse button on image it should open a new page in the same tab. It opens the new page in the same tab if i click left mouse button. However on clicking middle mouse button it opens the page in new tab...I want to prevent that. Below is the code.

```
render = () => {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <Link style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to="/card/new">
            <div>
                <Image
                />
            </div>
            </Link>
            <div className="footer">
                <div className="info">
                    <h4>{model.modelname}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          );
};
```

Can somebody guide me how to prevent the page from opening in new tab on middle mouse click? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a mouseDown event and then detect the middle button click like

```
handleMouseDown = (e) => {
   if(e.which === 2) {
      // do something on middle mouse button click
   }
}
```

You code might look like

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   handleMouseDown() {
       if(e.which === 2) {
          // do something on middle mouse button click
          // like this.props.history.push('/card/new');
       }
   }

   render() {
     <div style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} />
   }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```